# How to free an object after all slots were executed in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am facing an issue with Qt's signal and slot concept, as it is working asynchronously. I'm currently passing a pointer to an object which is created right before emitting a signal. I need to do this, because all receiving slots should use this object and be able to use the same state. I'm now running into problems, because I can't find a way to free the object after all the connected slots were executed. Is there an option for this?

Comment: Perhaps you should go into more detail about your approach? A textual description with some code as a backup explanation might be a good idea.

Comment: You may want to connect a signal to the object's slot [QObject::deleteLater()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) if I've understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QSharedPointer`. It will destruct automaically the object its holding when no one is referencing it anymore.